# Android 4.0 crush after loading image in imageView

Tags: android, android-imageview

I'm new at Android Studio and I'm trying to make a simple app. All I want it's to pick an image from Gallery and show it in an imageView.
this is what I got until now:

Activity:

```
package com.example.peyu.bellatrix_01b;

import android.content.Intent;  
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public final static String TAG_LOG = ImageActivity.class.getSimpleName();
public static final int PICK_IMAGE = 100;
public Uri imageURI;
public ImageView imgPicture;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_image);

    Button btnAbrirImagen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAbrirImagen);
    ImageView imgPicture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgPicture);

}

public void AbrirImagen(View v) {

    Intent photoPickerIntent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, PICK_IMAGE);

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {


    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE){

        imageURI = data.getData();
        imgPicture.setImageURI(imageURI);

    }


}
}
```

I Understand that the resultcode is getting a -1, but I don't know why... any idea?? thank you

This is the catlog:

09-01 22:34:50.145 20063-20063/com.example.peyu.bellatrix_01b W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41a53c98)
09-01 22:34:50.145 20063-20063/com.example.peyu.bellatrix_01b W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: uncaught exception occurred
09-01 22:34:50.146 20063-20063/com.example.peyu.bellatrix_01b W/System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=100, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/89391 flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.example.peyu.bellatrix_01b/com.example.peyu.bellatrix_01b.ImageActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-01 22:34:50.146 20063-20063/com.example.peyu.bellatrix_01b W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3592)
09-01 22:34:50.146 20063-20063/com.example.peyu.bellatrix_01b W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3635)
09-01 22:34:50.146 20063-20063/com.example.peyu.bellatrix_01b W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:151)
09-01 22:34:50.146 20063-20063/com.example.peyu.bellatrix_01b W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1390)
09-01 22:34:50.146 20063-20063/com.example.peyu.bellatrix_01b W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
09-01 22:34:50.146 20063-20063/com.example.peyu.bellatrix_01b W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
09-01 22:34:50.147 20063-20063/com.example.peyu.bellatrix_01b W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
09-01 22:34:50.147 20063-20063/com.example.peyu.bellatrix_01b W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-01 22:34:50.147 20063-20063/com.example.peyu.bellatrix_01b W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-01 22:34:50.147 20063-20063/com.example.peyu.bellatrix_01b W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
09-01 22:34:50.147 20063-20063/com.example.peyu.bellatrix_01b W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
09-01 22:34:50.147 20063-20063/com.example.peyu.bellatrix_01b W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-01 22:34:50.147 20063-20063/com.example.peyu.bellatrix_01b W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-01 22:34:50.150 20063-20063/com.example.peyu.bellatrix_01b W/System.err:     at com.example.peyu.bellatrix_01b.ImageActivity.onActivityResult(ImageActivity.java:70)
09-01 22:34:50.151 20063-20063/com.example.peyu.bellatrix_01b W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5535)
09-01 22:34:50.151 20063-20063/com.example.peyu.bellatrix_01b W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3588)
09-01 22:34:50.151 20063-20063/com.example.peyu.bellatrix_01b W/System.err:     ... 11 more
09-01 22:34:50.151 20063-20063/com.example.peyu.bellatrix_01b W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: calling UncaughtExceptionHandler
09-01 22:34:50.157 20063-20063/com.example.peyu.bellatrix_01b E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                Process: com.example.peyu.bellatrix_01b, PID: 20063
                                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=100, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/89391 flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.example.peyu.bellatrix_01b/com.example.peyu.bellatrix_01b.ImageActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3592)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3635)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1390)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
                                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                    at com.example.peyu.bellatrix_01b.ImageActivity.onActivityResult(ImageActivity.java:70)
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5535)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3588)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3635) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1390) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640) 
                                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: It doesn't work either. The app still crush.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You are declaring an imageView, but not initializing the same imageView.
2. You may not be aware of new uri permission model.

Answer (score 0):

The problem happens when you call `setImageURI` of `ImageView`.
I suggest you use this library below. This library will help you to create image file from that imageURI.

[EasyImage](https://github.com/jkwiecien/EasyImage)